# URL partial matching

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have two files: 
file 1

```
http://www.hello.com        http://neo.com/peace/development.html, www.japan.com,  http://example.com/abc/abc.html
http://news.net             http://lolz.com/country/list.html,www.telecom.net, www.highlands.net, www.software.com
http://example2.com         http://earth.net, http://abc.gov.cn/department/1.html
```

file 2:

```
www.neo.com/1/2/3/names.html
http://abc.gov.cn/script.aspx
http://example.com/abc/abc.html
```

file 2 are the search urls that is used for the partial match in file1 at column2. If it has the partial match it has to return the column 1 url with the partial match url in column 2 of file 1 like this:

Desired output:

```
http://www.hello.com    http://neo.com/peace/development.html, http://example.com/abc/abc.html
http://news.net
http://example2.com     http://abc.gov.cn/department/1.html
```

I tried this script which can give me exact match url pattern at column 2 which is as follows:

```
awk -F '[ \t,]' '
FNR == NR {
    a[$1]
    next
}
{    o = $1
    c = 0
    for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++)
        if($i in a)
            o = o (c++ ? ", " : "\t") $i
    print o
}' file2 file1
```

The output is :

```
http://www.hello.com    http://example.com/abc/abc.html
http://news.net
http://example2.com
```

Any suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: I think `grep -f file2 file1` should work for most of it except return ing column1 when it doesn't have a match

Comment: Why is `http://abc.gov.cn/department/1.html` in your output when it doesn't show up in `file 2`. I don't think I understand what you're going for here. Aren't you using `file 2` to search through `file 1` and return the entire line if one match is found and return just the first column if no matches are found?

Comment: @skamazin The URLs from File1 column 2 should get printed if there is a partial match to URLs from File2. `http://abc.gov.cn/department/1.html` is printed because there is a partial match to `http://abc.gov.cn/` in file 2. Thats how I am interpreting it.

Comment: Okay so it only has to match the first part of URL... that's rather difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk executable script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function getHost( url,        host ) {
    c = split( url, uarr, /[/]|:/ )
    for(j=1;j<=c;j++ ) {
        if( index( uarr[j], "." ) ) { host=uarr[j]; break }
    }
    return( host )
}

FNR==NR { host=getHost($1); if( host!="" ) hosts[host]; next }

# file2 FS="[[:space:]]|," file1
{
    end=""
    start = $1 "\t"
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        f1h=getHost( $i )

        for( f2h in hosts ) {
            if( length( f2h ) > length( f1h ) )
                { long_host=f2h; short_host=f1h }
            else
                { long_host=f1h; short_host=f2h }

            if( short_host!="" && index( long_host, short_host ) ) {
                if( end!="" ) end = end ", "
                end = end $i
                break
            }
        }
    }
    print start (end!="" ? end : "")
}
```

If it's called `awko` and `chmod +x awko`, then it can be run like:

```
awko file2 FS="[[:space:]]|," file1
```

It has at least the following assumptions:

- What you really want to match on are the host elements from the url
- Every valid host has at least one `.` in it
- A `\t` is the output separator between the first and any matching fields found

Breakdown:

- The `getHost()` function will return the first element with a `.` as the host
- `file2` hosts are loaded into the `hosts` array
- Externally, before `file1` is processed, `,` is added to the field separator with `FS="[[:space:]]|,"`
- In `file1` parsing, the first field is stored in `start`, and any host matches in subsequent fields are appended to `end`.
- Before hosts are compared, the longest one is found and set to `long_host` and the shortest as `short_host`.
- If the `short_host` is found inside the `long_host`, then append to `end` with some housekeeping for commas.
- Finally, print the `start` and any `end` produced via matches for every line in `file1`

Running this produces the desired output with the caveat that `\t` is always currently appended to `$1` in the output ( even when there are no matches ).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
function gethostname(url) {
    sub(/^[a-z]+:\/+/, "", url)
    sub(/^www[.]/, "", url)
    sub(/\/.*$/, "", url)
    return url
}
BEGIN { FS = "[ ,\t\r]*" }
NR == FNR {
    a[gethostname($1)]++
    next
}
{
    t = ""
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (gethostname($i) in a) {
            t = length(t) ? t ", " $i : $i
        }
    }
    print length(t) ? $1 "\t" t : $1
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1
```

Output:

```
http://www.hello.com    http://neo.com/peace/development.html, http://example.com/abc/abc.html
http://news.net
http://example2.com     http://abc.gov.cn/department/1.html
```

You can also make output in uniform:

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1 | column -t -s $'\t' -o '    '
```

See `man column`.

Script version with `column`:

```
#!/bin/sh    
awk -- '
    function gethostname(url) {
        sub(/^[a-z]+:\/+/, "", url)
        sub(/^www[.]/, "", url)
        sub(/\/.*$/, "", url)
        return url
    }
    BEGIN { FS = "[ ,\t\r]*" }
    NR == FNR {
        a[gethostname($1)]++
        next
    }
    {
        t = ""
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
            if (gethostname($i) in a) {
                t = length(t) ? t ", " $i : $i
            }
        }
        print length(t) ? $1 "|" t : $1
    }
' "$@" | column -t -s '|' -o '    '
```

Usage;

```
sh script.sh file2 file1
```